# Getting `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.propTypes.style')` in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-proptypes

After upgrading `"react-native": "0.70.0"` and `"react": "18.2.0"`, project is giving this error:

```js
ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.propTypes.style')
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

In Emulator it is showing as:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: what was your version before upgrading

Comment: before upgrading versions are "react": "16.11.0" and "react-native": "0.62.1".

Comment: I am getting the exact same error. Any idea of how to fix this ?

Comment: @GeoMukkath Downgrade the java version to 1.8. It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade the java version to 1.8. It will work.